# What is wrong with my argument?

Tags: number-theory

Euler's criterion says (assuming $p$ is a prime and $n$ not a multiple of $p$):
1. $n^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1$ (mod $p$), if there is an integer $x$ such that $x^2\equiv n$ (mod $p$)
2. $n^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1$ (mod $p$) if there is no such integer

I have to prove the first part as homework. So here's what I did (+ some explanation of course):
$$
n^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv (x^2)^\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \quad \text{(mod $p$)}
$$

But I'm felling it's not correct. Because if i don't assume such $x$ exist, I can still prove $n^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1$
$$
n^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv k \\
n^{p-1} \equiv k^2 \equiv 1 \\
k \equiv 1
$$

What's wrong?

Comment: $k^2\equiv 1$ does NOT imply $k\equiv 1$! Your proof of 1. is correct anyway.

Comment: thanks, I was carelessly assuming if $k^2 \equiv 1$ then $k^2=1$, but it's only true for $k$ not $k^2$. (I was assuming $k$ is in the range $0$ to $p$ but not $p$)

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong with this one: $n^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv (n^{p-1})^{\frac{1}{2}} \equiv 1^{\frac{1}{2}} \equiv 1$ (I didn't want to create another stupid question)

Comment: From $(n^{\frac{p-1}{2}})^2 = 1$ you can conclude that $n^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = 1 $ or $n^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1$ , not only $1$

Comment: @kptlronyttcn: It can be dangerous to introduce non-integers, and one's intuitions about them, into an argument about integers. Example, the exponent $1/2$ in the comment above.